# Union table to itself limiting to a maximum number of rows

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I have this table

```
ID         OtherId                info1                  info2                  startDate
---------- ---------------------- ---------------------- ---------------------- -----------------------
7160       1                      0                      0                      2001-01-01 00:00:00.000
7160       2                      3.83                   4.42                   2001-01-01 00:00:00.000
7160       3                      0                      0                      2001-01-01 00:00:00.000
7160       4                      3.83                   4.42                   2001-01-01 00:00:00.000
7160       5                      3.83                   4.42                   2001-01-01 00:00:00.000
7160       6                      4.36                   0                      2001-01-01 00:00:00.000
7160       7                      0                      0                      2001-01-01 00:00:00.000
```

I want to union the same table to itself but limiting to a maximum number of rows.
For example limit to 16 rows:

```
7160       1                      0                      0                      2001-01-01 00:00:00.000
7160       2                      3.83                   4.42                   2001-01-01 00:00:00.000
7160       3                      0                      0                      2001-01-01 00:00:00.000
7160       4                      3.83                   4.42                   2001-01-01 00:00:00.000
7160       5                      3.83                   4.42                   2001-01-01 00:00:00.000
7160       6                      4.36                   0                      2001-01-01 00:00:00.000
7160       7                      0                      0                      2001-01-01 00:00:00.000
7160       1                      0                      0                      2001-01-01 00:00:00.000
7160       2                      3.83                   4.42                   2001-01-01 00:00:00.000
7160       3                      0                      0                      2001-01-01 00:00:00.000
7160       4                      3.83                   4.42                   2001-01-01 00:00:00.000
7160       5                      3.83                   4.42                   2001-01-01 00:00:00.000
7160       6                      4.36                   0                      2001-01-01 00:00:00.000
7160       7                      0                      0                      2001-01-01 00:00:00.000
7160       1                      0                      0                      2001-01-01 00:00:00.000
7160       2                      3.83                   4.42                   2001-01-01 00:00:00.000
```

I tried cross join but it's not really what I want.
Could you please give me a hint?

Thanks!

Comment: You can do `select top (16) u.id, u.otherid, ... from (select ... from T union all select ... from T) u order by -- whatever`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select from your table with a cross join to a tally table (or an "inline" tally table in the form of a cte):

```sql
WITH N0 AS (
    SELECT n
    FROM (VALUES (0), (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9))V(n)
), Tally AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY @@SPID) As N
    FROM N0 As ten, N0 As hundred --, N0 As thousand -- and so on
)

SELECT TOP 16 ID, OtherId, info1, info2, startDate
FROM TableName
CROSS JOIN Tally
ORDER BY N, OtherId
```

That will give you your expected results.